# Same code, different Eclipse Project, different results from database (java)

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse

I have really a strange strange situation. It is driving me crazy. I was playing with the code 1 hour and at the end I figure out that it works as it should BUT in another project. I want to get some information out from a database.

So I run this:

```
    public class DBtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
        kkp.processInput("USERNAME,PASSWORD");
    }

}
```

Which calls this:

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import de.vogella.mysql.first.load_login;

public class KnockKnockProtocol {

    public String theOutput[];

    public void processInput(String theInput) throws Exception {

        String[] data = theInput.split(",");

        byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(data[1].getBytes());
        String pass = new String(encoded);

        load_login get = new load_login();
        theOutput = get.nalozi(data[0], pass);

        for (String n : theOutput) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my code for calling DB and get results:

```
    package de.vogella.mysql.first;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class load_login {
    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;
    int count = 0;
    String user, password, ssl, tls, smtp_domain, smtp_port, signature = null;

    String[] rezultat = new String[3];

    public String[] nalozi(String mail, String pass) throws Exception {
        try {

            // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Setup the connection with the DB
            connect = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?????"
                            + "user=?????&password=?????");

            String checkSql = "select * from OFFLINE where (user_mail='" + mail
                    + "' AND user_pass='" + pass + "')";

            Statement st = connect.createStatement();
            resultSet = st.executeQuery(checkSql);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                rezultat[0] = user = resultSet.getString("user_mail");
                rezultat[1] = password = resultSet.getString("user_pass");
                rezultat[2] = ssl = resultSet.getString("ssl_protocol");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            close();
        }

        return rezultat;
    }

    private void close() {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (connect != null) {
                connect.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Sorry for all this code. So the point is that in one Eclipse project the results are right and in the other the results are NULL -> I get 3 times written null. Is this a bug or I am missing something very important?

Thx for any help.

Comment: Did you copy paste the source code?

Comment: The other project was in a different PC? I mean because you're accessing the localhost database...

Comment: It is on the same PC and yes I copy paste the code.

Comment: Print stack trace in your empty catch block in your database code

Comment: Wow, can you please write the code how to do that..

Comment: So I put this in the database code:

    StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

            for(int i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(elements[i]);
            }

And in both cases I get this:

java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1503)
de.vogella.mysql.first.load_login.nalozi(load_login.java:27)
KnockKnockProtocol.processInput(KnockKnockProtocol.java:22)
DBtest.main(DBtest.java:5)

Comment: Really nobody knows the possible answer to this? :/

Comment: Ok at the end i figured out the problem..I'm ashamed to admit that I forgot to include JDBC Driver for MySQL (Connector/J).
Actually I don't know why Eclipse didn't noticed me..
Anyhow.. a big FAIL for me :)